# What happens to "lost answers"?

Tags: support, answers

I was answering a question and a phone call came in.  To answer the call I went away from my MSE answer which was under construction, when the call ended I could not find the answer or even the question anymore.  What will become of my lost answer?

Comment: There could have been a deletion of the Question by its owner, which is permitted so long as no Accepted or upvoted Answer has been posted on it.  With enough reputation you would gain the privilege of seeing recently deleted Questions, but I suspect this Tool does not include self-deletions.

Comment: If the Question is still there, it is likely that your "draft" of the under-construction Answer will still be visible (to you) under the Question.

Comment: @hardmath: Actually, with two posted answers, the OP cannot delete their question with a binding vote.

Comment: Upon further review my technique wouldn't have worked, but then I want to clear the draft.  Thanks.

Comment: Your draft is cleared the next time you start a new Answer.